# Как сделать фонетический разбор слов "павильон" и ему подобных?

Tags: фонетика

В словах *павильон, бульон, каньон* пишется О после Ь, а произносится как "Й**Ь**О". По всем школьным правилам два звука после мягкого знака обозначают только буквы " Е, Ё, Ю, Я". Некоторые школьники, у которых хороший "фонематический слух", пишут транскрипцию [павил**Ь**й**Ь**он] (**Ь** знак в данном случае обозначает не звук, а просто мягкость согласного  звука). И, действительно, мы же не произносим[павил**Ь**он], [бул**Ь**он]. Но как тогда быть с правилом?  В школьной программе нет никаких оттеночных звуков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос господину Фурсенко. Почему школьная программа не соответствует.
На самом деле ваша формулировка "два звука после мягкого знака обозначают только буквы  Е, Ё, Ю, Я" не верна. Слово "только" здесь неприменимо. И если в какой-то школьный учебник залезло подобное утверждение, то его надо менять. Или хотя бы дополнить простой оговоркой, что это относится к собственно русским словам. А в *иноязычных* словах буква О после мягкого знака читается как ЙО (со смягчением предшествующего согласного). 
Ничего особо криминально в такой оговорке нет, ведь никакми школьными правилами не предписано иное чтение сочетания "ЬО" в каких-либо случаях. Путаница может возникнуть только при чтении некоторых украинских фамилий (Грiсьо - [грисё]). Но это далеко за рамками школьной программы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Согласна со словом "только", но вот про иноязычные слова, кроме орфографического правила, ничего не сказано (ничего не дано в разделе "ФОНЕТИКА" о фонетическом разборе подобных слов). И я, конечно, детям скажу об особенностях произношения иноязычных слов, а как быть, если в тестах встречается подобный вопрос, что там могут заложить в ответ?

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужного правила в школьном учебнике нет. Я и предлагаю дополнить.

Кстати, о каком вообще учебнике идёт речь? Их сейчас, вроде, я профессионально далек не только от школы, но и от русского языка вообще, потому не в курсе. 

В отношении тестов - попробуйте спросить на форуме gramota.ru
Там есть люди, владеющие вопросом более чем профессионально.

Comment: Dafnija! Простите, не сразу прочитала комментарий. В тестах вполне может быть такой вопрос, и, конечно же , заложен ответ, предусматривающий, что буква О в данном слове (и подобных) обозначает два звука.

Comment: Ой, а вопрос -то давнишний. Не сразу обратила внимание. Это благодаря Галактиону он появился первым в "текущих вопросах"

Answer (score 2):

Dafnija! А Вы учитель? Так категорично говорите про "все школьные правила".  В школьных учебниках в разделе  "Фонетика" сказано, что буквы Е,Ё,Ю,Я обозначают два звука в определенных позициях. Слова ТОЛЬКО не видела ни в одном учебнике, да  его  и не может быть.  А фонетический разбор слов  типа павильон есть, есть подобные слова и на экзамене в 9 классе. К сожалению, не умею здесь печатать транскрипцию, не получаются надстрочные знаки. Но зачем обозначать мягкость в транскрипции буквой Ь, если можно поставить сверху запятую? Кстати, в словах типа соловьи, воробьи буква И тоже обозначает два звука.

Comment: Резниченко приводит транскрипцию *кларнета* - {рн'е}, а произношение {рнэ} - неправильное. Вопрос : какой гласный звук обозначен в {рн'е}?!! Смягчается **н** или нет, мы вроде всегда **э** тянем. Тут какая-то ошибка явно.

Comment: Что-то не уловила связи с вопросом... Звук гласный одинаковый - Э. Хоть при мягком Н, хоть при твердом. Да, в некоторых словарях в транскрипции употребляют Е, желая показать мягкость предыдущего согласного. Я не согласна. С университетских времен твердо запомнила - Е,Ё,Ю, Я - это буквы, в транскрипции не используются. Конечно, это условности, но хотелось бы единообразия в знаках.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и понял. Просто удивило оформление сетевого словаря, разве так можно...

Comment: Такое оформление транскрипции я видела и в академических словарях. (Имею в виду, изданных Институтом Русского языка)

Comment: Уважаемая  Ларf, да, я учитель.И прекрасно знаю про "определённые позиции". Но вопрос не о буквах Е, Ё, Ю, Я, а о букве О после мягкого знака в иноязычных словах типа ПАВИЛЬОН  и прочие.  Вы внимательно прочтите вопрос, пожалуйста.Никто мягкость звуков не обозначает  с помощью Ь, просто нет возможности написать в данный момент транскрипцию с запятой. И в институте мы учили про слова типа ВОРОБЬИ, где говорилось об и с оттенком йотирования, но ведь опять же в школьных правилах о букве И не пишется, что она может обозначать иногда  2 звука.

Comment: Не скажу за все учебники, но у Бабайцевой есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если *иноязычное слово* "павильон" преобразовать в *русскоязычное слово* "павильйон" либо *русскоязычное слово* "павильён", тогда не потребуются:

1) ни выкрики типа "Это вопрос к господину Фурсенко.",

2) ни "оговороки" к правилу,

3) ни разглагольствования про "криминальность" либо "некриминальность" "оговорок" к правилам,

и т. п.

Comment: Англ. pavilion, фран. pavillon, голл.. paviljoen, украинский **павiльйон**!
Стоит задуматься об упорядочивании фонетического правописания...
Мы же пишем - мильён, давайте писать - каньйон или каньён. Вопрос уже не к Фурсенко, а к Ивану Александровичу Стрельцову : когда мы сможем прочитать и оценить Ваши предложения по реформе русской фонетики, то есть по ее бесспорному отображению на письме? Напишите на форуме короткое исследование на эту тему, если Вам доступна эта опция.

Comment: А кто так пишет - мильён?

Comment: Разумеется, это адаптация. А писали и пишут так все :
> Н. С. Лесков. Божедомы (1868) Да его… спину **мильён раз** оскорбляли, да он и то не жаловался, потому что поделом.

>Сергей Юрский. Петров день (1988) ― Правильно, ― говорит, ― отгадал ты загадку. **И вот тебе за это мильён!** /// **И мильён Анастасов замутился** ― вроде не из волшебных он шести чисел возник, а вовсе из другого источника, какого ― неведомо.

Comment: > **мильё** — milieu m. 1. Среда, людское
окружение кого л. Неужели так преступно со со
стороны патриота, если он берет то что зовут
Французы le milieu, среду, таковою как она
есть. К. Леонтьев Аспазия Лаприди. // РВ1871
6 755. Атмосфера и все milieu в… …
Исторический словарь галлицизмов
русского языка

*Павильён* очень хорошо смотрится по-русски! Ничуть не хуже *флешки*.

Comment: Ну уж не все. Поиск выдает как ошибку. В словарях нет. В художественных произведениях может употребляться, чтобы передать особенности речи героя.

Comment: *Мильон терзаний* - можно и так, конечно. Особенности русского произношения очень особенные. Значит, оставляем павильоны в покое.>*Месьо/месьё/месье, же не манж па сис жур*...

Comment: Мы-то преобразовать можем, и детям меньше придётся заморачиваться, как правильно,  но пока подобное написание не будет закреплено официально в лингвистических словарях, оно будет считаться ошибкой. И, действительно, я с вами согласна,останется только как способ передачи особенностей речи героя.

Answer (score 0):

Вот правило:

Буква «и» после мягкого знака тоже состоит из двух звуков — [йи] при звуко- буквенном анализе. Данное правило актуально для слогов, как в сильной, так и в слабой позиции.
Приведем образец звуко-буквенного онлайн разбора:
- соловьи [салав’йи´], на курьих ножках [на ку´р’йи’х' но´шках], кроличьи [кро´л’ич’йи], нет семьи [с’им’йи´], судьи [су´д’йи], ничьи [н’ич’йи´], ручьи [руч’йи´], лисьи [ли´с’йи].

**Но:
Гласная «о» после мягкого знака транскрибируется как апостроф мягкости [’] предшествующего согласного и [о], хотя при произнесении фонемы может слышаться йотированность: бульон [бул’о´н], павильон [пав’ил’о´н] (почтальон, шампиньон, шиньон, компаньон, медальон, батальон, гильотина, карманьола, миньон и прочие).**